# Resources for building/launching a Solana Oracle

Tags: program, oracles, opensource

I'm looking for any demos, tutorials, or open-source code for building and connecting to a Solana-based Oracle. Would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Oracles providing VRFs have simple game examples on Github:

https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-flip

https://github.com/orao-network/solana-vrf

https://github.com/evanmarshall/cross-pile